# External Controls for FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a requirement in our application to show the object controls beyond the canvas. Currently there is no way to do this in FabricJS directly, so I created my own controls which move with the object. I have the controls working almost perfectly, but I am unable to figure out how to make the controls work with rotation. The thing that I want is the opposite end of the current control being used should be static, the way it happens when the angle is zero.

Here is current work - https://jsfiddle.net/debjitbis08/wzaefg5m/163/

Code

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="custom-control" style="position: fixed;border: 1px solid green;">
    <div class="control-point top-left"></div>
    <div class="control-point top-right"></div>
    <div class="control-point bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="control-point bottom-right"></div>
    <div id="top-control" class="control-point top"></div>
    <div id="right-control" class="control-point right"></div>
    <div id="bottom-control" class="control-point bottom"></div>
    <div id="left-control" class="control-point left"></div>
    <div class="control-point rotate-control"></div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid blue"></canvas>
</div>
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.control-point {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.top-left {
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
}

.top-right {
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}

.bottom-left {
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
}

.bottom-right {
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}

.top {
  top: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.right {
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  right: -5px;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.left {
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  left: -5px;
}

.rotate-control {
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

canvas.setZoom(2);

fabric.Canvas.prototype.getAbsoluteCoords = function(object) {
  return {
    left: (object.left + this._offset.left) * canvas.getZoom(),
    top: (object.top + this._offset.top) * canvas.getZoom()
  };
}

const customControl = document.getElementById('custom-control');

function positionCustomControl(obj) {
  var absCoords = canvas.getAbsoluteCoords(obj);

  const objWidth = obj.get('width') * obj.get('scaleX') * canvas.getZoom();
  const objHeight = obj.get('height') * obj.get('scaleY') * canvas.getZoom();

  customControl.style.width = objWidth + 'px';
  customControl.style.height = objHeight + 'px';

  const canvasLeft = document.getElementById('c').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const canvasTop = document.getElementById('c').getBoundingClientRect().top;

  customControl.style.left = (absCoords.left - (objWidth / 2) - (canvasLeft * (canvas.getZoom() - 1))) + 'px';
  customControl.style.top = (absCoords.top - (objHeight / 2) - (canvasTop * (canvas.getZoom() - 1))) + 'px';
  customControl.style.transform = 'rotate(' + obj.get('angle') + 'deg)';
}

/* const rect = new fabric.Rect({

  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  top: 200,
  left: 200,
  fill: '#FF0000'
});
 */

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://unsplash.com/photos/K_eO9l8X9us/download?ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8M3x8fHx8fDJ8fDE2OTgzMjM0NzJ8&force=true&w=1920', function(rect) {

  rect.set({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    top: 200,
    left: 200,
  });
  canvas.add(rect);
  positionCustomControl(rect);

  rect.on('moving', function() {
    positionCustomControl(rect)
  });
  rect.on('scaling', function() {
    positionCustomControl(rect)
  });
  rect.on('rotating', function() {
    positionCustomControl(rect);
  });

  canvas.renderAll();


  let dragStartPosition = null;
  let rectStartPosition = null;
  let scaling = false;
  let initialScaledWidth = rect.width * rect.scaleX;
  let initialScaledHeight = rect.height * rect.scaleY;
  let initialTop = rect.top;
  let initialLeft = rect.left;


  customControl.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    if (scaling) return;

    dragStartPosition = {
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    };

    rectStartPosition = {
      x: rect.left,
      y: rect.top
    };

    initialTop = rect.top;
    initialLeft = rect.left;
    initialScaledWidth = rect.width * rect.scaleX;
    initialScaledHeight = rect.height * rect.scaleY;
  });

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (dragStartPosition && !scaling) {
      const deltaX = event.clientX - dragStartPosition.x;
      const deltaY = event.clientY - dragStartPosition.y;

      rect.set({
        left: rectStartPosition.x + deltaX / canvas.getZoom(),
        top: rectStartPosition.y + deltaY / canvas.getZoom()
      });

      canvas.renderAll();
      positionCustomControl(rect);
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    dragStartPosition = null;
  });

  let currentControlPoint = null;
  let startScalePoint = null;

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    const target = event.target;

    if (target.classList.contains('control-point')) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      scaling = true;
      currentControlPoint = target.className.split(' ')[1]; // e.g., "top-left", "bottom-right", etc.
      startScalePoint = {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
      };
      //previousScaleX = rect.scaleX;
      //previewScaleY = rect.scaleY;
      initialTop = rect.top;
      initialLeft = rect.left;
      initialScaledWidth = rect.width * rect.scaleX;
      initialScaledHeight = rect.height * rect.scaleY;
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (scaling) {
      const offsetX = (event.clientX - startScalePoint.x) / canvas.getZoom();
      const offsetY = (event.clientY - startScalePoint.y) / canvas.getZoom();
      let scaleFactor = 1;

      let previousScaleX = rect.scaleX;
      let previousScaleY = rect.scaleY;


      switch (currentControlPoint) {
        case 'top-left':
          scaleFactor = (initialScaledWidth - offsetX) / initialScaledWidth;
          rect.set({
            left: initialLeft + (initialScaledWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2),
            top: initialTop + (initialScaledHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2),
            scaleX: scaleFactor,
            scaleY: scaleFactor
          }).setCoords();
          break;
        case 'top-right':
          scaleFactor = (initialScaledWidth + offsetX) / initialScaledWidth;
          rect.set({
            left: initialLeft - (initialScaledWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2),
            top: initialTop + (initialScaledHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2),
            scaleX: scaleFactor,
            scaleY: scaleFactor
          }).setCoords();
          break;
        case 'bottom-left':
          scaleFactor = (initialScaledWidth - offsetX) / initialScaledWidth;
          rect.set({
            left: initialLeft + (initialScaledWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2),
            top: initialTop - (initialScaledHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2),
            scaleX: scaleFactor,
            scaleY: scaleFactor
          }).setCoords();
          break;
        case 'bottom-right':
          scaleFactor = (initialScaledWidth + offsetX) / initialScaledWidth;
          rect.set({
            left: initialLeft - (initialScaledWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2),
            top: initialTop - (initialScaledHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2),
            scaleX: scaleFactor,
            scaleY: scaleFactor
          }).setCoords();
          break;
        case 'top':
        case 'bottom':
            scaleFactor = (initialScaledHeight + offsetY) / initialScaledHeight;
          rect.set({
            scaleY: scaleFactor
          }).setCoords();
          break;
        case 'right':
        case 'left':
            scaleFactor = (initialScaledWidth + offsetX) / initialScaledWidth;
          rect.set({
            scaleX: scaleFactor
          }).setCoords();
          break;
      }


      canvas.renderAll();
      positionCustomControl(rect);
    }
  });


  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    scaling = false;
    currentControlPoint = null;
    lastKnownAngle = null;
    initialScaledWidth = rect.width * rect.scaleX;
    initialScaledHeight = rect.height * rect.scaleY;
    initialTop = rect.top;
    initialLeft = rect.left;
  });

  let lastKnownAngle = null;

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.classList.contains('rotate-control')) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      scaling = true;
      const center = canvas.getAbsoluteCoords(rect);
      //initialAngle = Math.atan2(center.top - event.clientY, event.clientX - center.left);
      currentControlPoint = 'rotate';
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (currentControlPoint === 'rotate') {
      const center = canvas.getAbsoluteCoords(rect);
      const currentAngle = Math.atan2(center.top - event.clientY, event.clientX - center.left);

      // Initialize lastKnownAngle if not set
      if (lastKnownAngle === null) {
        lastKnownAngle = currentAngle;
      }

      const angleDifference = currentAngle - lastKnownAngle;
      const rotationDelta = -1 * angleDifference * (180 / Math.PI);

      rect.rotate(rect.angle + rotationDelta);
      canvas.renderAll();
      positionCustomControl(rect);

      lastKnownAngle = currentAngle; // Update the last known angle
    }
  });
});
```